# How to prevent AutoLayout from resetting view frames?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I have a view with AutoLayout and it works nicely with different screen sizes. There's one element on the screen though that moves around depending on user actions. Whenever I navigate down to a different screen then back to this view, this element gets reset to its original position.

I understand why this happens but how can I prevent it? I do want it to be setup correctly initially but not after the first time.

Comment: How are you currently moving the floater?  Are you setting its frame directly, or are you modifying its constraints?

Comment: this shouldnt happen, there is no reason for it to happen. could you post your code to come back to this view? also, check under the viewdidappear or viewwillappear if you are setting in any way the position of this element.

Comment: @robmayoff I move use by setting its frame. Perhaps I should adjust the constraints?

Comment: @LuisOscar are you sure Luis? It doesn't make sense but it happens, I do not override viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear.

Comment: "Perhaps I should adjust the constraints" Yes, you should -- if you're using constraints, you shouldn't have any setFrame: calls in your code. So either turn of auto layout, or adjust the constraints.

Comment: If you move it around by setting its frame then when you present another viewcontroller and dismiss it you should see exactly what you saw before presenting it. the auto layout is used for setting the frame and everything the first time the view is loaded. It could happen if you rotate the device for example but not by the means you are saying. The behavior you describes sounds more like if you were instantiating a new viewcontroller, in which of course the states are all fresh. thats why i want to know how you move between these view controllers.

Comment: @rdelmar I am going to try this one but sounds like the right answer. Care to put it here as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @LuisOscar Luis, I can guarantee you I am not instantiating it again or rotating the device (which is disabled by the way). I put breakpoints in every "did" and "will" methods that could possibly happen and this is what really is happening. I am simply moving to a 2nd VC and back to this one. Try for yourself. It's weird but true.

Comment: Go to https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/.  There are three videos about auto layout.  Watch them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Autolayout you should never use setFrame/setBounds because as you've seen Autolayout ignores them and rewrites them when it updates.

The solution is to change the constraints. A constraint has a parameter called `constant` which is the only thing you can change on a constraint after it has been created. You can also add/remove extra constraints when you need to move NSViews around.

There is a video from WWDC 2012 that had a very good example of how to move views with AutoLayout.

Answer (score 3):

The only solution I found is, Implement `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

It will invoke the `layoutSubviews` method just after the view is loaded..

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    @try
    {
         // Adjusting controls.
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception)
    {
        NSLog(@"%s\n exception: Name- %@ Reason->%@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__,[exception name],[exception reason]);
    }
}
```

Comment: toooooo goooood, this is a delegate method that works for ios also :):)